# Cannot add to db from routes.py file

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask blueprint to structure my code in a file called routes.py, but a problem of application context arises when i try to add something to my database (Data) within a route (/update). How do i get my app into my routes.py such that flask would identify it. Please I would appreciate any help. Below is my code:

routes.py 'update route'

```
from flask import Blueprint,render_template, redirect, request, session,flash
from .extensions import db
from .models import *
import requests
import concurrent.futures
from tle import Tle
from config import Config
rc = Tle()
main = Blueprint('main', __name__)
conf = Config()

@main.route("/update")
def update():
    satellite_ids = [43137,49399,44881,44387,43780,43678,42778,42759,40911,40910,40909,40907,40906,39444,39417,7530]  # Add more satellite IDs as needed
    marker_data = {}
    path_data = {}

    def fetch_satellite_data(sat_id):
        try:
            response = requests.get(f'https://api.n2yo.com/rest/v1/satellite/positions/{sat_id}/{conf.LAT}/{conf.LON}/{conf.ALT}/300/&apiKey={conf.APIKEY}')
            if response.status_code == 200:
                my_json = response.json()
                pos = my_json["positions"]
                posi = pos[2]
                lat = posi["satlatitude"]
                long = posi["satlongitude"]
                az = posi["azimuth"]
                el = posi["elevation"]
                al = posi["sataltitude"]
                name = my_json["info"]["satname"]
                
                # radius = rc.r_coverage()
                radius = rc.r_cover(float(al))
                # radius = 10000
                
                
                new = Data(latitude = lat, longitude= long, altitude = al, elevation=el, name=name, azimuth=az, norad_id = str(sat_id)) 
                db.session.add(new)
                db.session.commit()

                marker_data[f"{sat_id}"] = {"lat": lat, "lon": long,"al":al,"el":el,"az":az, "name":name, "radius":radius}
                # Retrieve path data
                pathlist = [(pos[p]["satlatitude"], pos[p]["satlongitude"]) for p in range(len(pos) - 1)]

                path_data[f"{sat_id}"] = pathlist
                
                
            else:
                print("Transaction count exceeded")
                flash("Server API not connecting", "danger")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            flash("Error fetching data for satellite ID: " + str(sat_id), "error")

    # Use concurrent.futures to fetch data in parallel
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(fetch_satellite_data, satellite_ids)

    print(marker_data)
    if request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
        return {"marker_data": marker_data, "path_data": path_data}
    return render_template("test.html")
 


def ishorizon(el):
    return el>0
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from .extensions import db,admin
from .routes import main
from config import Config
def create_app(config_class = Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)
    db.init_app(app)
    admin.init_app(app)
    app.register_blueprint(main)
        
    return app
```

Thank you

Comment: You are within the application context within you route function but you leave it when you call fetch_satellite_data using multithreading. You will have to avoid using any of the flask context locals within your multithreaded code.

Comment: Ohh okay that sounds more like it. Does this mean i don't have to specify with app.app_context(): before adding data into my database?

Comment: Flask will automatically push an application and request context when calling a route function, this will allow you access to `current_app, g, request and session` and functions such as `flash` that make use of these internally. You are leaving the context when you call multithreading making your call to `flash` one source of this error and you may be accessing one of the context local variables within your database code which you have not shown.

Comment: Is there a way I could still use multi-threading? Is there a way I could transfer my app context into a different thread?

Comment: Okay I have figured it out, I put all my processes and threading in my run.py file then called the create_app function as app in that python file, then any operation I needed to do on my database, I used the app.